# How do I setup Wordpress Multisite in it's own directory?

Tags: multisite

I have installed Wordpress 4.1 in it's own directory. After this I Setup a wordpress network with 3 other sites.

There is already a live site running on http://abc.com  [using abc.com as example]
The folder I have created in root to install wordpress is new_abc

The Sites are in the format:

```
abc.com/new_abc
abc.com/new_abc/s1
abc.com/new_abc/s2
abc.com/new_abc/s3

codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
```

The Above article states that we need to make changes to wordpress Dashboard --> General --> Site address (URL)   to     abc.com  from     abc.com/new_abc  and copy the index.php and .htaccess file.

However post setup of Wordpress Multisite, we do not get that option at all in the wordpress Dashboard.

Is it possible to make the Site Adress (URL) in the WP_options table on the MySQL database? Does this need to be done on wp_options for all network sites?

Post this following the steps

```
<code> http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory </code>
```

Should it fix my issue or should I take care of anything else..?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from moving and editing index.php and moving .htaccess, you can try editing wp-config.php with adding a constant for the address of the WordPress install and the home dir. More info on how to do this - [read here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WordPress_address_.28URL.29).

I can't promise you that this will work, but at least it's worth a try!

Please let me know if it worked!